# (python widgets) assign variable to slider value?

Tags: python, widget, slider

I don't have any sample code with me but does anybody know how to assign a variable to a slider value. For example, you have a simple slider, can move the slider so the slider's value changes, and this change affects the value of this assigned variable. I'd also like to be able to put this variable into a function and display that function beside the slider, which would also change as one moves the slider.

Comment: You need to explain which toolkit you're using. "python widgets" isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and pasted code from the [ipywidget docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html):

```py
from IPython.display import display
w = widgets.IntSlider()
display(w)
slider_value = w.value
```

Edit:
Still not entirely sure if I got that right and I do not have IPython installed so I am not 100% confident that my solution will work but let me try to help you:

```py
#You of course have to declare that function or use calculated_value = 3*slider_value like in your comment
calculated_value = yourFunction(slider_value)
#If I remember correct that should display the variable in jupyter
calculated_value
```

But I have no idea what you're trying to explain with that function next to the slider. Please be a little more specific with that.

Comment: Luca, thank you for this response, it answers the first part of my question. What I mean by function is say you have a function y=3*x with x assigned to a slider value. As you move the slider to the value 2 (x=2), y =6, and displays the number 6 beside the slider, and so on

Comment: @RaphaelHatami I edited my answer, I hope this helps, if not I can maybe try something else